# How do you translate this enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions method call to Swift?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift

The sample application called [CocoaDragAndDrop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaDragAndDrop/Listings/CocoaDragAndDrop_DragDropImageView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000384-CocoaDragAndDrop_DragDropImageView_m-DontLinkElementID_6) uses a method called `enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions`. Here it is in Obj-C:

```
    [sender enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:NSDraggingItemEnumerationConcurrent 
        forView:self
        classes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSPasteboardItem class]] 
        searchOptions:nil 
        usingBlock:^(NSDraggingItem *draggingItem, NSInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {


            if ( ![[[draggingItem item] types] containsObject:kPrivateDragUTI] ) {

                *stop = YES;

            } else {

                [draggingItem setDraggingFrame:self.bounds contents:[[[draggingItem imageComponents] objectAtIndex:0] contents]];
            }
        }];
```

How would you write this code in swift?

I tried it like this:

```
sender.enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions(
    enumOptions: NSDraggingItemEnumerationOptions.Concurrent,
    forView: self,
    classes: [NSPasteboardItem.self],
    searchOptions: NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey,
    usingBlock: { (draggingItem: NSDraggingItem, idx: Int, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in

        // ...

    }
)
```

And I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert the expression's type '(enumOptions: NSDraggingItemEnumerationOptions, forView: DragDropImageView, classes: $T5, searchOptions: NSString!, usingBlock: (NSDraggingItem, Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)' to type 'NSPasteboardItem.Type'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signature in **Swift** is

```
func enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions(enumOpts: NSDraggingItemEnumerationOptions, 
  forView view: NSView, classes 
  classArray: [AnyObject], 
  searchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject], 
  usingBlock block: (NSDraggingItem!, Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)
```

- We can omit parameters type in callback, because they are get from declaration, 
  that makes code more clean
- The callback is the last parameter so we can use [trailing closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_160) syntax

**The call to method**

```
sender.enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions(
  .Concurrent,
  forView: self,
  classes: [NSPasteboardItem.self],
  searchOptions: [NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey:self]) 
    {(draggingItem, idx, stop)  in
    // Code here
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Signature has changed in OS X 10.11.

```
func enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions(
  enumOpts: NSDraggingItemEnumerationOptions,
  forView view: NSView, 
  classes classArray: [AnyClass], 
  searchOptions: [String : AnyObject], 
  usingBlock block: (NSDraggingItem!, Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)
```

// so, we need to adapt as follows:

```
func f(sender:NSDraggingInfo) -> () {
  var v:NSView = NSView()
  let classArray:[AnyClass] = [NSPasteboardItem.self]
  let item = NSPasteboardItem()
  let searchOptions:[String:AnyObject] = [NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey:v]
```

Answer (score 0):

This compiles, and so shows the correct syntax. I define the parameters explicitly to clarify the types:

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

func f(sender:NSDraggingInfo) -> () {

   var v:NSView = NSView()
   let classArray:[AnyObject] = [NSPasteboardItem.self]
   let item = NSPasteboardItem()
   let searchOptions:[NSObject:AnyObject] = [NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey:v]

sender.enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions(
  NSDraggingItemEnumerationOptions.Concurrent,
  forView: v,
  classes: classArray,
  searchOptions: searchOptions,
  usingBlock: { (draggingItem: NSDraggingItem!, idx: Int, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in

    // ...

  }
)
}
```